# Correctly using Promise.resolve

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have a a changePassword function returning a promise:

```
function changePassword(userName, oldPassword, newPassword) {
  return new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
      someAsyncFunction(userName, oldPassword, newPassword, function(ok) {
        if (ok) resolve(); else reject();
      }
    });
}
```

I need to modify this function so that newPassword can be either a value or a promise:

```
// functionReturningNewPasswordValOrPromise is a function returning either a value
// or a promise that will resolve with a value 
function changePassword(userName, oldPassword, functionReturningNewPasswordValOrPromise) {
   return new Promise( ...
```

If functionReturningNewPasswordValOrPromise returns a value (the new password), everything proceeds as above.

However if functionReturningNewPasswordValOrPromise returns a a promise, it will run first (ie prompting the user). If resolved (ie with the new password string) changePassword will continue resolution with that value. If rejected changePassword itself will reject.

I understand I need to use Promise.resolve(thenable) somehow but not sure how to proceed.

Thx!

(I need an answer in ES6 so that I can use it in IE with polyfill .. no ES7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution I came up with is:

```
function changePassword(userName, oldPassword, functionReturningNewPasswordValOrPromise) {
  var getNewPassPromise=functionReturningNewPasswordValOrPromise(email);
  return Promise.resolve(getNewPassPromise).then(function(newPassword) {
    return changePasswordWithVal(email, oldPassword, newPassword);
  });
}

// do the real work
function changePasswordWithVal(userName, oldPassword, newPassword) {
  return new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
      someAsyncFunction(userName, oldPassword, newPassword, function(ok) {
        if (ok) resolve(); else reject();
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Judging from that code `newPasswordValOrPromise` is not a promise but instead a function that returns a promise. You never mentioned that in your question.

Comment: you are very right SpiderPig, I didn't state my question properly because I didn't understand the issue well in general. I now amended my question. I can now understand your answer above better but it's still faulty - you need to change the 'then' function parameter to something else than newPassword to make it work.

Comment: Actually you can use the same name for two different variables. Therefore it is not necessary to change the parameter name to something else.

Answer (score 2):

It is often an anti-pattern to have values which might or not be promises, then try to check which they are, or have special logic to handle this, or convert them to promises. The same applies to functions which might return such maybe-a-promise-maybe-not values.

So we need to go back to where your function is being called and where it is getting the `newPassword` parameter. Let's assume it's something like this, using a `getNewPassword` function which is currently designed to return either a value or a promise:

```
changePassword(userName, oldPassword, getNewPassword())
```

The first and probably best approach would be to simply change the definition of `getNewPassword` so it always returns a promise--even if it's already resolved with some value. Then you can write the above as

```
getNewPassword() . 
  then(newPassword => changePassword(userName, oldPassword, newPassword))
```

and you don't have to change your original definition of `changePassword` at all.

Even if you cannot change the definition or signature of `getNewPassword`, it seems clumsy to build the logic for handling a parameter which might or might not be a promise into a specific interface such as `changePassword`. Instead, I would do that at the calling point, via

```
Promise.resolve(getNewPassword()) . 
  then(newPassword => changePassword(userName, oldPassword, newPassword))
```

In other words, absorb the impact of the ambiguous design of `getNewPassword` at the point where it is called, rather than making people downstream worry about it.

#### A general solution

If you really want to deal with functions which take parameters which might or might not be promises, you could generalize this:

```
function promisify_arguments(fn) {
  return function(...args) {
    return Promise.all(args) . then(vals => fn(...vals));
  };
}
```

If for some reason you have promises but not ES6 support, then in ES5:

```
function promisify_arguments(fn) {
  return function() {
    return Promise.all(arguments) . then(function(vals) {
      return fn.apply(0, vals));
    });
  };
}
```

This takes a function which expects non-promise paramters, and returns a modified function which can be called with promises for some or all parameters, and waits for all its promise-valued parameters to resolve, then invokes the original function with the resolved values as parameters, returning a promise whose value is the resulting value.

You can use this to transform your `changePassword` function as

```
var changePasswordWhereNewPasswordMayBePromise = promisify_arguments(changePassword);
```

and then use `changePasswordWhereNewPasswordMaybePromise` instead of `changePassword`. This has the potential advantage that if `userName` or `oldPassword` ever are provided as promises, it will automatically do the right thing.

Comment: thank you torazaburo I learned a lot from your answer ! as I'm creating a 'library' with this interface I don't want to put the parameter handling logic at the point of call. Also I can't use ES7 features as I need to support IE so only ES6 (with some polyfill) .. I updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Were some ES7 features used in my answer?

Comment: I meant the =>, you're right it's not es7 but I need IE support so poyfills ok but not shims ... thanks

Comment: There is no polyfill or shim for arrow functions. You either need to transpile your code, or rewrite the functions using ES5 syntax. I have provided an example for `promisify_arguments`.

Comment: your ES5 example still uses arrows

Comment: @kofifus Sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to handling `newPassword` being a password or a promise is:

```
function changePassword(userName, oldPassword, newPassword) {
  return Promise.resolve(newPassword).then(password => new Promise((r, e) =>
      someAsyncFunction(userName, oldPassword, password, ok => ok ? r() : e())));
}
```

`Promise.resolve(x)` returns `x` when `x` is a promise (*), and a promise resolved with value `x` when it isn't.

There is good advice in other answers, but I believe this is all that was asked for.

---

*) In most implementations, but not all (Safari being an exception), I observe that `Promise.resolve(p) === p` when `p` is a promise, but this is a detail. The important bit is it acts like the original promise in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to wrap someAsyncFunction into a promise based function.
e.g.

```
function someAsyncFunctionP(userName, oldPassword, newPassword) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    someAsyncFunction(userName, oldPassword, newPassword, function(err) {
      if(err) reject(err); else resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

Then to allow `newPassword` to be a Promise you can write this.

```
function changePassword(userName, oldPassword, newPassword) {
  return Promise.resolve(newPassword).then(function(newPassword) {
    return someAsyncFunctionP(userName, oldPassword, newPassword);
  });
}
```

Comment: ok great thank you ! sorry about the wrong code now amended so you can remove that part of your answer. I still don't understand how to reject changePassword (with my err value) if the newPassword promise rejected ?

Comment: also your code doesn't work, you pass newPassword (a promise) to the 'then' in 'return Promise.resolve(newPassword).then'